# How do I layout my UIScrollView when the user changes to landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm very new to landscape adaptations. My UIScrollView with an embedded UIImageView works perfect in portrait, but when I switch to landscape it's incredibly messed up.

I tried the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

But it's to no avail. When I rotate the view it still throws the image into the bottom left corner.

How do I layout a UIScrollView so when I shift to landscape, it stays centered? (Pretty much identical behavior to Photos.app is what I'm striving for.)

In my `scrollViewDidZoom:` I have the following as well, if relevant (it keeps it centered as the user scrolls):

```
CGRect newImageViewFrame = self.imageView.frame;

// Center horizontally
if (newImageViewFrame.size.width < CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.bounds)) {
    newImageViewFrame.origin.x = (CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(self.imageView.frame)) / 2;
}
else {
    newImageViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
}

// Center vertically
if (newImageViewFrame.size.height < CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.bounds)) {
    newImageViewFrame.origin.y = (CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(self.imageView.frame)) / 2;
}
else {
    newImageViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
}

self.imageView.frame = newImageViewFrame;
```

Comment: Are you using AutoresizingMask ?

Comment: If the scroll view is a subview of `self.view`, you probably meant to use `self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;` (not `self.view.frame`)